# Kubernetes ssh into pods fails

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to ssh into my pod with this command

```
kubectl --namespace=default exec -ti pod-name /bin/bash
```

I get this error:

```
Content-Type specified (plain/text) must be 'application/json'
```

The process gets stuck and I have to close the terminal.

I was able to ssh into my pods before I re install kubernetes in my machine. Is this an issue with latest kubernetes releases?

Answer (score 3):

You're not trying to "ssh", you're forwarding your standard input and receiving a standard output over HTTP through the Kubernetes API.

That said, you're using Docker 1.10 whereas Kubernetes doesn't support it yet. Check this out https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/19720

**edit**:
Kubernetes supports Docker 1.10+ since the 1.3.0 release.

Comment: The fix https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/20873 which bumped go go-dockerclient version was merged in kubernetes HEAD. You should be able to use docker v1.10 with kubernetes, even though it's not officially supported yet.